# json showing error no value for total even if the value is present

Tags: android, json

Log cat showing following error.

> 06-07 03:12:49.829 29544-29544/com.example.aamer.aurangabad W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for total
>           at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
>           at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
>           at com.example.aamer.aurangabad.BusinessProfile$4.onResponse(BusinessProfile.java:162)
>           at com.example.aamer.aurangabad.BusinessProfile$4.onResponse(BusinessProfile.java:142)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
>   06-07 03:13:51.675 29544-29544/com.example.aamer.aurangabad W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   06-07 03:13:51.685 29544-29544/com.example.aamer.aurangabad W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

**and here is my code to decode the json.**

```
try {

         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
         JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("result");

         JSONObject json_obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

          name.setText(json_obj.getString("business_name"));

          one_mobile.setText(json_obj.getString("mobile_one"));


           two_mobile.setText(json_obj.getString("mobile_two"));
           email.setText(json_obj.getString("email_id"));
           address.setText(json_obj.getString("address"));

           working_hours.setText(json_obj.getString("working_hour"));
           phone = json_obj.getString("mobile_one");

            businessrating.setText(json_obj.getString("total"));

            Glide.with(BusinessProfile.this)               .load("http://ansofexpert.com/dashboard/uploads/"+json_obj.getString("feature_image"))
                 .thumbnail(0.1f)
                 .dontAnimate()
                 .centerCrop()
                 .into(feature_image);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

here is the json response from server

> {"result":[{"business_id":"1",
>   "business_name":"Mainland China Restaurant",
>   "mobile_one":"2147483647",
>   "mobile_two":"2147483647",
>   "email_id":"ashishingles@rediffmail.com",
>   "address":"Daultabad T Point, Daultabad Road, Sharnapur, Aurangabad - MS - 431001, Maharashtra, India","area_id":"9",
>   "city_name":"aurangabad",
>   "establish_date":"17-05-2018",
>   "about_business":"Spread over 4 acres of beautifully landscaped are for a rustic look.",
>   "working_hour":"10:00 am - 10:00 pm",
>   "category_id":"38",
>   "subcategory_id":"2",
>   "feature_image":"581e9e09692a4a6e5837b5bd89bc2877.jpg",
>   "register_date":"09-05-2018",
>   "expire_date":"22-05-2018","status":"0"},
>   {"total":"3.4"}]}

Comment: `total` is not nested within the same element

Answer (score 1):

json_obj does not contain "total" in your json string. 
Please replace the following line:

```
json_obj.getString("total")
```

with

```
json_obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
json_obj.getString("total")
```

and try again

Answer (score 1):

If you format the JSON, you'll get your answer. See

```
{
  "result":[
    {
        "business_id":"1",
        "business_name":"Mainland China Restaurant",
        "mobile_one":"2147483647",
        "mobile_two":"2147483647",
        "email_id":"ashishingles@rediffmail.com",
        "address":"Daultabad T Point, Daultabad Road, Sharnapur, Aurangabad - MS - 431001, Maharashtra, India",
        "area_id":"9",
        "city_name":"aurangabad",
        "establish_date":"17-05-2018",
        "about_business":"Spread over 4 acres of beautifully landscaped are for a rustic look.",
        "working_hour":"10:00 am - 10:00 pm",
        "category_id":"38",
        "subcategory_id":"2",
        "feature_image":"581e9e09692a4a6e5837b5bd89bc2877.jpg",
        "register_date":"09-05-2018",
        "expire_date":"22-05-2018",
        "status":"0"
    },
    {
        "total":"3.4"
    }
  ]
}
```

You might need to do:

```
JSONObject json_obj_2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
json_obj_2.getString("total")
```